# Need help explaining a small bit of code

Tags: c++

So, im new to coding and trying to get into c++. I was trying to get through the second problem on Project Euler and thought i had a good grasp on how to approach it. Hours later, i gave up and decided to look it up.

```
int x = 0;
int y = 1;
int z = x + y;
int sumeven = 0;
while (z < 4000000)
{
    x = y;
    y = z;
    z = x + y;
    if (z % 2 == 0)
    {
        sumeven += z;
    }
}
cout << sumeven;
```

thr problem im having is with the

```
x=y; y=z; z=x+y;
```

everything else i understand.

can someone explain this to me please. Im not sure how i would have known to do this without looking it up.

Comment: it's explained right in the problem statement: [Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms.](https://projecteuler.net/problem=2).  If this formulation is confusing, look around for other Fibonacci implementations, as there are other ways to code this.

Comment: Do you know what assignment is?

Comment: Your question is too broad. Without a *precise* description of what *exactly* you *do* and *don't* understand, the answer is going to amount to a significant portion of the C++ language specification. Do you know what a variable is? Do you what a variable assignment is? Do you know what an integer is? Do you know what an operator is? Do you know what `operator+` does for two integers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Z` is always being set to be the sum of the previous two numbers, where `x` is "2 numbers ago" and `y` is "the previous number".

So, after `z` is calculated, the next iteration has to be set up. We now want "2 numbers ago" to be what had been `y` in this iteration:

```
x = y;
```

And we want "the previous number" to be the `z` that was just calculated:

```
y = z;
```

Now we calculate the new z:

```
z = x + y;
```

Answer (score 0):

This example tries to calculate summation of even numbers of Fibonacci sequence, each number in Fibonacci sequence is the result of adding last two numbers. So here is what's happening :

1. Start from 0 : `int x = 0; \\x is 0 now`
2. The second number is 1 : `int y = 1; \\y is 1 now`
3. Add them to get 3d number : `int z = x + y; \\z is 1 now as it's result of adding 0 and 1`
4. Copy `y` to `x` : `x = y; \\so x is 1 now, as you can see we are advancing our variables in Fibonacci sequence, It means x is the second number of sequence now`
5. Copy `z` to `y` : `y = z; \\as I said, we are advancing in sequence so now y is 3d element of sequence (it was 2nd before) and it's value is 1 now`
6. Calculate `z` base on last two elements (`x` and `y`) : `z = x + y; \\ so here z would be our 4th element which of course it's calculated by last two so it's value would be 2 as x and y were both 1`
7. Test if it's an even number : `if (z % 2 == 0)`
8. If it is, add it to our summation variable : `sumeven += z;`
9. Go to step 4